# win10 keyboard shortcut for rightclick on file/folder?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

Is there any built in keyboard short cut to open the context menu of a file folder (the pane that opens when you right click it)? For example, I can press `F2` to rename a file/folder, but I would like it to open the entire context menu.

Edit: Based on an answer I have to share my keyboard which instead of the suggested key has a emoji key. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your keyboard is appropriately configured, there's a context menu button in the general lower right corner of the main portion of the keyboard. Barring that feature, Shift-F10 provides the same function, system focus dependent, of course.

[image: context menu key]

Image courtesy of [Peltier Tech website](https://peltiertech.com/context-menu-key/)